# 'IOException: The cloud file provider is not running', when trying to delete 'cloud' folder

Tags: .net, windows, virtual-drive

I'm building a virtual drive Windows desktop app using IT Hit User File System library. Sometimes I get an IOException with message: 'The cloud file provider is not running.', when I'm trying to remove one of the folders that are marked as 'cloud' (synchronized with cloud) from local file system.

Before removing it I check if it exists in the file system, so there is no way I'm trying to remove folder that doesn't exist.
All the googled references to 'The cloud file provider is not running.' error are related to OneDrive, I couldn't find anything on this issue from development perspective.

Can this exception not be related to OneDrive and be caused by any other reason?
What are possible reasons I get this exception?

I can't wrap my head around it. I'm struggling to grasp possible reasons for several days.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.